# How to print escaped characters with princ

Tags: display, characters, print

When Emacs shows an integer value in the minibuffer, or as an output to IELM, it shows three representations of it -- octal, hex and as character:

```
ELISP> 10
10 (#o12, #xa, ?\C-j)
```

This is really nice, and I'd like to use something like that in my programs. Now, while I can use `format` to show an integer as octal (with `%o`) or with hex (with `%x`), I don't know how to get the nice formatted character as the above. `%c` will actually print the character without escaping, and will, for example, print a line feed for 10.

I have tried the `print-escape-*` variables, without success:

```
ELISP> (let ((print-escape-newlines t)
             (print-escape-nonascii t)
             (print-escape-multibyte t)
             (print-escape-control-characters t))
             (concat "char: " (string 10)))
"char: 
"
ELISP> (let ((print-escape-newlines t)
             (print-escape-nonascii t)
             (print-escape-multibyte t)
             (print-escape-control-characters t))
             (format "char: %s" (string 10)))
"char: 
"
ELISP> (let ((print-escape-newlines t)
             (print-escape-nonascii t)
             (print-escape-multibyte t)
             (print-escape-control-characters t))
             (format "char: %s" 10))
"char: 10"
ELISP> (let ((print-escape-newlines t)
             (print-escape-nonascii t)
             (print-escape-multibyte t)
             (print-escape-control-characters t))
             (format "char: %c" 10))
"char: 
"
```

What I want is to get a string with the escaped character, to later print with `princ`.

I've tried looking into the source for IELM and the minibuffer, but they seem to delegate printing to other parts of Emacs, and I couldn't find how it's done.

How can I get those printed the way I described?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Thanks, I really didn't expect the tag to not be related to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `(format "(#o%o, #x%x, ?\\%s)" 10 10 (single-key-description 10))`

You might need to use `(princ (format "(#o%o, #x%x, ?\\%s)" 10 10 (single-key-description 10))`, depending on what you're doing with it.

You can get this yourself by looking at the code that implements `M-:`: command `eval-expression`.  You'll see that it uses this, for a character:

`(eval-expression-print-format 10)`

That's an equivalent answer to what I show above.

(To see `eval-expression` at work, step by step, you can use `M-x debug-on-entry`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works!